# SequelizeValidationError "l'ID User cannot be not null"

Tags: sequelize.js

I can't create a new post in my database, I tried to retrieve the user's token after authentication but I can't retrieve it and store it in the post so that the post is created. Need help
My postman request :

```
{
    "content": "my content",
    "likes": 0
    "usersId": 1
}
```

Error on postman :

```
{
    "error": {
        "name": "SequelizeValidationError",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Post.UserId cannot be null",
                "type": "notNull Violation",
                "path": "UserId",
                "value": null,
                "origin": "CORE",
                "instance": {
                    "id": null,
                    "title": "Un titre",
                    "content": "un contenu",
                    "picture": "une image",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-02-08T14:28:08.444Z",
                    "createdAt": "2022-02-08T14:28:08.444Z"
                },
                "validatorKey": "is_null",
                "validatorName": null,
                "validatorArgs": []
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Post extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      models.Post.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: {
          allowNull: false,
          name: "userId"
        }
      })
    }
  };
  Post.init({
    content: DataTypes.STRING,
    comments: DataTypes.STRING,
    attachment: DataTypes.STRING,
    likes: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Post',
  });
  return Post;
};
```

controllers :

```
const models = require('../models');
const  {User, Post} = models;
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.createPost = (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);
    const userId = decoded.id
     const userIdFound = await User.findOne({where: {id: userId}});
     const {body} = req;
    const post = Post.create({...body, userIdFound})
    .then((response) =>{
        res.status(201).json(post);
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
        res.status(400).json({ error })
    })
    .catch(error => res.status(500).json(error))
};
```

thank you very much for your help (I'm still a beginner, there will surely be some mistakes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You indicated `userIdFound` as a prop (with the whole user model instance) while calling `create` method but you need `userId` prop with just  a user id:

```js
const userIdFound = await User.findOne({where: {id: userId}});
const {body} = req;
const post = Post.create({...body, userId: userIdFound.id })
```

OR

```js
const {body} = req;
const post = Post.create({...body, userId })
```